# fast reports : add space between two masterdata bands

Tags: fastreport

I cant figure out how to add space between two master data bands.Nothing seems to work. I would like to write something into that space as well but I cant seem to be able to fit anything in between.

I am using Fast Reports 5.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add empty child band to MasterData if you want to add space between different rows of same masterdata band
If you want add space between Masterdata1 and Masterdata2 bands - add empty MasterData3 with RowCount = 1